# I want to add image and text side by side in a trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt and leading swipe action when swipe in a tableview swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uiswipegesturerecognizer, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I know when we set the height of cell to 91 it shows both image and text vertically but I want horizontally side by side without setting height.

Comment: Post code what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it with UIContextualAction. Try making your own custom component if you really need it to look like that.

Answer (score 0):

there is trick we can do that in existing image view in swipe like
deleteAction.image = textToImage(inImage: UIImage(named: imageName)!, drawText: imageTitle, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
you need to create your own function textToImage